# Weather App in iOS 7 - can't get the top location to delete or move

Tags: applications, ios

I can move or delete any of the locations on the list except the one at the top. Help.

Comment: With iOS 5 and 6, you could remove that location by disabling a "local weather" setting. That has been removed in iOS 7.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that the one at the top is always based on current location - meaning it's not a favorite you've set, it's using the GPS to get your location.

All the others are configurable.

Comment: @Nina You're very welcome...  please upvote and accept as the answer if this was helpful to you :)